# Change the color of the bibliometric map in Packages

Tags: r

I'm having trouble changing the color of the bibliometric map using R. I intend to change the color to black and white. But I don't know the syntax used for that.
The code structure I use to generate the map looks like this:

```
conceptualStructure(M, field = "ID", method = "MCA", quali.supp = NULL, quanti.supp = NULL, minDegree = 2, clust = "auto", k.max = 5, stemming = FALSE, labelsize = 10, documents = 2, graph = TRUE)
```

Please help me, what code can I use to change the color of the map, background and text in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `conceptualStructure` before, nor know what package it comes from (assuming it isn't base R), but I *think* you should be able to make it black and white by just specifying as such in the theme. E.g.

```
conceptualStructure(M, 
   field = "ID", 
   method = "MCA", 
   quali.supp = NULL, 
   quanti.supp = NULL, 
   minDegree = 2, 
   clust = "auto", 
   k.max = 5, 
   stemming = FALSE, 
   labelsize = 10, 
   documents = 2, 
   graph = TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

That may just be a ggplot2 thing though. In which case, i'm not sure I can help